# Pattern Matching to recognise Bold Characters in string

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse this string and extract bold number out od it .
I dont have a suitable regex for 
 1. useInput can be
    ="0067711990999999**1955**0515070999999999999N9+01**23**1+99999999..";

```
Pattern pattern;
    String regex="\\s*-?\\d+(?:\\s*[-+/*]\\s*-?\\d+)+\\s*";
    pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(userInput);
```

The problem is i dont find any regex to match the bold String.

i need this in a Map-Reduce program.

Thanks

Comment: In this context, what's a "bold" number?

Comment: It an year like above **1955* and temperature *23*.

Comment: Font changes themselves are not characters.  Perhaps your input in raw form has some kind of sequence which indicates a font change; you could determine that sequence and match on it.  Note that if this sequence is HTML, you could go very wrong with parsing; aside with the usual problems with matching HTML tags, you might need to worry about CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reading .odt files, perhaps http://www.jopendocument.org/ is the way to go?

Comment: ok For odt it is helpfull but for .log files I will have problem . But anyway thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
String myString = "0067711990999999*1955*0515070999999999999N9+01*23*1+99999999";
// matches all number series (one or more consecutive digits) 
// between * characters. * normally matches any character and 
// so has to be escaped using \, which in a string becomes \\,
// i.e the regular expression is actually \*([0-9])\*
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*([0-9]+)\\*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // the parantheses in the regex creates a capturing group, i.e.
    // a substring within the match that can later be extracted. 
    // the "1" here means we're picking up the value of the first 
    // (and in this case, only) capturing group, which is the 
    // actual numbers (i.e. not including the * characters)
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

would print

```
1955
23
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes . But the thing is in the input *1995* and *23* mean bold. *'s are not included in the string and i am reading these from a log file and .odt file.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure regex can help you here. See the comment by @geekosaur above. Please update your question to include an _actual_ userInput string, as read from the log file/.odt file.

Comment: ok. input logs are 006779195005150704..................999999999999N9+00031+999999999.......
006771199991954051507004..................999999999999N9+00111+999999999.......
00677119909999991955051507004..................999999999999N9+01231+999999999.......
00677119909999991956051507004..................999999999999N9+00121+999999999.......
00677119909999991957051507004..................999999999999N9+00121+999999999.......
00677119909999991954051507004..................999999999999N9+00511+999999999.......
00677119909999991954051507004..................999999999999N9+00111+999999999

Comment: 0067711990999999*1954*051507004..................999999999999N9+00*11*1+999999999 line in this log every log has an year and temp. I need to extract it.

Comment: Ok, there seems to be a pattern in at least some of the strings, and extracting the year/temp from those should only be a matter of using substring(begin,end), but if you're reading .odt files, see my other answer.

Comment: OK substring is fine for extracting year. But for temperature it is not fessible. Again if logs change then i have change the code. i am trying to think of some logic so that it recognise the pattern dynamically. Help me out.! Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at jopendocument yet? What you want to do is read the .odt file using an API. From there you can probably extract formatting and so on.